# Copy Files recursively without folders

Tags: powershell

I am new to powershell, I am looking for a way to copy files from a nested directory structure into a single folder. I do not want to recreate the folder structure, I simply want to copy all files within the whole structure into a single folder.

I know how to do this via DOS command prompt. but I am not able to replicate in powershell.

This is what I am doing in DOS:

```
for /d %a in (*) do @copy %a\*.* "Z:\Image\Test\Migration\test1"
```

Comment: What you are after is not hard and can be done in virtually all scripting languages.  It cool to be new to something, but the first place to start is [the help files/docs for any product](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/). See the built-in help files for details and examples:  ```Get-Help -Name Get-ChildItem -Detail``` and the examples ```Get-Help -Name Get-ChildItem -Examples```, then  ```Get-Help -Name CopyItem -Examples```, then see the docs on loops (ForEach, ForEach-Object, etc...).

Comment: Thus you can refactor what you have into  PowerShell almost exactly as you have it in cmd.exe; then the help on [PowerShell loops](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/4542.powershell-loops.aspx#:~:text=PowerShell%20also%20support%20some%20universal%20loop%20like%3A%20The,performs%20an%20operation%20until%20the%20condition%20is%20true.).  There is tons of free online PS training on Youtube, TutorialSport.com, etc.  Then add this to your info arsenal.:  Search for ***'PowerShell File and Folder Management***, via your favorite search engine and on Youtube.

Answer (score 0):

As per my comment, by spending just a day in the PS Help and Youtube videos, one can easily refactor your cmd.exe command to PS.

I'll show the verbose form (preferred approach), for easier readability, and long-term maintenance for you and those who would share this with or have to follow you to maintain your stuff.

```
Get-ChildItem -Path 'D:\Temp\CopiedStuff' 
# Results
<#
Get-ChildItem : Cannot find path 'D:\Temp\CopiedStuff' because it does not exist.
#>

# Check before you serialize the results
Get-ChildItem -Path 'D:\Temp' -Recurse -File | 
Copy-Item -Destination 'D:\Temp\CopiedStuff' -WhatIf
# Results
<#
...
What if: Performing the operation "Copy File" on target "Item: D:\Temp\Word\HSGCopy - Copy.docx Destination: D:\Temp\CopiedStuff\HSGCopy - Copy.docx".
What if: Performing the operation "Copy File" on target "Item: D:\Temp\Word\HSGCopy.docx Destination: D:\Temp\CopiedStuff\HSGCopy.docx".
What if: Performing the operation "Copy File" on target "Item: D:\Temp\Word\Test.docx Destination: D:\Temp\CopiedStuff\Test.docx".
What if: Performing the operation "Copy File" on target "Item: D:\Temp\Word\WES - Copy.docx Destination: D:\Temp\CopiedStuff\WES - Copy.docx".
What if: Performing the operation "Copy File" on target "Item: D:\Temp\Zips\book1.zip Destination: D:\Temp\CopiedStuff\book1.zip".
What if: Performing the operation "Copy File" on target "Item: D:\Temp\Zips\book2.zip Destination: D:\Temp\CopiedStuff\book2.zip".

#>

Get-ChildItem -Path 'D:\Temp' -Recurse -File | 
Copy-Item -Destination 'D:\Temp\CopiedStuff'
```

The q&d (quick and dirty), ad-hoc, throw-away, CLI way.
Again, don't do this in production scripts, well, scripts period because as documented, it's bad practice. Meaning the shorthand/alias stuff shown.

```
gci 'D:\Temp' -r -File | cp 'D:\Temp\CopiedStuff'

# Validate copy
Get-ChildItem -Path 'D:\Temp\CopiedStuff'
# Results
<#

    Directory: D:\Temp\CopiedStuff


Mode                 LastWriteTime         Length Name
----                 -------------         ------ ----
...
-a----         06-Apr-20     21:52           3537 book1.zip
-a----         06-Apr-20     21:52           3537 book2.zip
-a----         29-Aug-20     20:32          13417 HSGCopy - Copy.docx
-a----         30-Aug-20     02:15          13404 HSGCopy.docx
-a----         06-Feb-20     15:22          11832 Test.docx
-a----         21-Jan-21     20:58          12273 WES - Copy.docx 
#>
```